# Primitive of $e^{ikx}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Is there anyone have an idea how to find the primitive of $e^{ikx}$?

I know that we have to compute $\int_0^x e^{ikt} dt$, but it is not clear for me how to do that.

Comment: If it's confusing for you, replace the $x$ in the upper bound of the integral with an arbitrary variable like $t$, then change it back when you're done.

Answer (score 2):

Following normal rules for indefinite integration,

> $$\int_0^x e^{ikt} dt = \frac{e^{ikx}-1}{ik}$$

since $i$ and $k$ are both constants, when $k \neq 0$.

Comment: @JohnMcMaster $\frac{e^{ikx}}{ik}$

Comment: This is true if $k\neq0$.